# How do we count the number of occurrence from left to right and continue until we have consecutive numbers?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, logic

So the code that I wrote, is for the number of occurrence. Suppose in the sample part which is mentioned, if I give an input Array of {2,1,1,1,3}, it will give me the count of Number 2 occurrence as 1. Now, I'm struggling to write the code in a manner so that it gives me the count only if it's continuous from left to right. Suppose, if my array is {1,1,1,2,0}, only then it will give me the total occurrence of 1 as 3, but not if it's {1,0,1,2,1} or {0,0,1,1,1} or {1,1,2,2,1}

```
    static void Evaluate_V5B(int[] window, int[] PayCombos,)
            {
                int[] Counters1 = new int[3];

                for (int index0 = 0; index0 < 5; index0++)
                {
                    Console.Write("{0} ", window[index0]);
                    int symbol = window[index0];
                    Counters1[symbol]++;
                }
                Console.WriteLine();

    for (int indexJ = 0; indexJ < Counters1.Length; indexJ++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}", Counters1[indexJ]);
                }
}
```

Comment: What if there's `{0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0}`? Count two `1`s or only one? What if there's `{0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0}`?

Comment: Can I ask: Do you mean that you want to find the longest unbroken sequence of a given number, and return the length? So for instance, for the sequence {1,1,2,2,1}, the occurence for both 1 and 2 is 2 (2x 1 sequentially, 2x 2 sequentially)?

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen  I just want the counts from left to right. Suppose I'm playing a game, so we'll consider if it starts from the first count. So, we'll consider it only from the extreme. I've no use if I get {0,1,1,1,1}, so only if we start from the number we get, and that continues till a number of places. So, even for {1,1,0,0,0} I've 2 counts of 1. My count of 3 0's is not important. Similarly, here in {2,2,2,0,0}, I just need the counts of 2's as it's important.

Comment: OK, What about the sequence {1,1,2,2,1}, what would you return from this? Do you return 2x 1's and 2x 2's, or do you have to ask "how many 1's?" or "how many 2's" and get only that number?

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen Only 2 1's will be it. That will be count. I don't require the 2 2's or the last 1.

Comment: And how would the code know that you'e not interested in the 1's?

Answer (score 0):

This will take the 1st element in the array and return continuous occurrences from left to right. If that element found anywhere else it will return 0 as count:

```
static void Evaluate(int[] array)
{
    var count = 1;
    var first = array[0];

    for (int i = 1; i < array.Length; i++)
    {
        if(array[i] == first)
        {
            count++;
        }
        else{
            for (int j = i + 1; j < array.Length; j++)
            {
                if(first == array[j]) {
                    count = 0;
                    break;
                }
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine($"Count of Number {first} occurrence is {count}");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This function will find the number of continuous occurrences of a specific number `num` in the array `nums`, if it is the first number.

```
static int ContinuousOccurrences(int[] nums, int num)
{
    if (nums[0] == num)
    {
        int continuousOccurrences =
            nums.TakeWhile(x => x == num).Count();

        int totalOccurrences =
            nums.Where(x => x == num).Count();

        if(continuousOccurrences == totalOccurrences)
        {
            return continuousOccurrences;
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

If you want to know the number of continuous occurrences of the first number, call the function this way:

```
ContinuousOccurrences(nums, nums[0])
```